# Accessing a Windows file folder from Oracle Forms 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I would like to have a block in an Oracle 10g form that would show all of the PDF files in a particular folder on the user's C drive.  The user should at least be able to double-click on the file to open it, and ideally be able to delete and rename the files, too.

The list of files should show the filename (obviously) as well as the size and date of the file.

The forms are running on a Solaris 10 server, accessed via Internet Explorer.

Any thoughts on how, or even if, that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get [WebUtil](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/forms/htdocs/webutil/webutil.htm). It is a Free Forms add-in product specifically designed to solve the problem you are having. And a few other.

Comment: +1. We use WebUtil extensively, especially for file uploads in our app

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it will do exactly what I need.